# Вызов метода возвращает None вместо значения

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу такой код:

```py
class Sentence:
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content = content

    def show(self):
        x1 = random.randint(0, 3)
        print(x1)


second = Sentence([0, 1, 2, 3])
print(second.content)
print(second.show())
```

Когда вызываю `show`, функция возвращает `None`.

Как поправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def show(self):
    x1 = random.randint(0, 3)
    return x1
```

Comment: до безумия оказалось просто, спасибо вам большое